# I seem to have have a perma-pregnant dweller in Fallout Shelter. How do I fix this?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I have a pregnant dweller that still hasn't given birth after 3 days. Is this a glitch? Or is there something that I can do to speed along her delivery? I have made sure that I have enough living space for new dwellers, and other women have gotten pregnant and given birth since she was initially impregnated.

Comment: I've found the answer to this in case anyone else has had this exact problem. From my other comment: "Apparently this is a glitch that happens if you have demolished or upgraded the Living Quarters that the baby was conceived in. Since the new dweller spawns in the place where it was conceived, the AI doesn't know where to put it, so the woman just stays pregnant. I hope this helps. Bethesda knows about the problem."